# ISDATE producing error for DATE (datatype) value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a MyDate(datatype DATE) column in My_Table

```
MyDate
2016-11-01
0001-01-01
2016-08-01
```

When i execute the following query

```
SELECT  ISDATE(MyDate),* FROM My_Table
```

I am getting the following error

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Argument data type date is invalid
>   for argument 1 of isdate function.

I thought the issue may the date `'0001-01-01'`. But when i execute

```
SELECT ISDATE('0001-01-01')
```

It is working as expected and produced the result `0`.(ie not a date)

But

```
DECLARE @V AS DATE = '0001-01-01' --no error
SELECT ISDATE(@V) --error
```

This is producing the same error. 
What i am wrong here?

**Edit**:- If i remove the values `'0001-01-01'` from Mytable, the query `SELECT ISDATE(MyDate)` is working properly without any datatype conversion.

Comment: Why are you using ISDATE against a column of datatype DATE? Under what circumstances do you think it will return FALSE?

Comment: @MartinSmith, if ISADTE('0001-01-01') also return TRUE then ok, i can understand, `then why this error for date value?`

Comment: @AbdulRasheed because function `ISDATE` requires string or expression which can be transformed to string. Date will not be casted into string, because of [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql)

Comment: There's definitely some confusion here over *what you're trying to achieve*. By **definition**, anything contained in a `date` column is going to be a valid date. Before you started writing this code, what were you setting out to try to do?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ,`anything contained in a date column is going to be a valid date`, but why this ISDATE(`valid_date`) is produced error? and `ISDATE('0001-01-01')` and `ISDATE('ABC')` is getting result. Also if i remove the values '0001-01-01' the query ISDATE(MyDate) will work without any conversion.

Comment: Is your most important problem right now why the developers chose not to invest time to allow you to use a function to ask a question to which the only possible answer is yes? If not, explain what *led* you to trying to call `ISDATE` on a `date` value in the first place and we may be able to offer practical help. Otherwise, this is just trivia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISDATE ( expression )

Arguments

expression
Is a character string or expression that can be converted to a character string. The expression must be less than 4,000 characters. **Date and time data types, except datetime and smalldatetime, are not allowed as the argument for ISDATE.**

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql

Comment: My column is NOT NULL DATE field, if i remove the values '0001-01-01' the query `ISDATE(MyDate)` will work without any conversion.

Answer (score 2):

`ISDATE()` can only evaluates STRING so try like this.

```
DECLARE @V DATE = '0001-01-01'
SELECT ISDATE(CAST(@V AS VARCHAR(30)))
```

Comment: Incidentally, `ISDATE` returns false for the date string `0001-01-01`, but that probably has to do with the internal logic, not related to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that Sarthak Grover's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49002322/3094533) covers exactly the reason why you get a syntax error. I only posted my answer to elaborate a bit and to add an explanation on the reason why `isdate('0001-01-01')` returns false, when it's a perfectly valid value for the `Date` data type.

The entire point of the [`ISDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql) function is to determine if the argument can be converted to a valid [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql), [`time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql) or [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql), under the current [`DATEFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) settings, simply by using [`cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) (as apposed to [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql), that accepts a style parameter thus does not depend on the current date format settings.
Passing an argument of type `DATE` to the `ISDATE` function is nonsensical, since if the type of the argument is `DATE`, there is no need to check it.

Also, **it is explicitly forbidden** to pass an argument of date and time data types, except `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, as Sarthak Grover pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49002322/3094533) (+1 from me, btw).

the `ISDATE` function will return false even if the argument is convertible to a date value, if it's representing a date value before 1753-01-01, or after 9999-12-31.
This is because the value range of the `DATETIME` data type is from `1753-01-01 00:00:00` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59.997`.

Here is a simple demonstration ([try it yourself on rextester](http://rextester.com/OAEU73897)):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    DateString varchar(20),
    Comments varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO @T (DateString, Comments) VALUES
('1752-12-31', 'will always return false'),
('1753-01-01', 'will always return true'),
('2018-02-27', 'depends on dateformat'),
('2018-27-02', 'depends on dateformat');

SET DATEFORMAT YMD;

SELECT  DateString, 
        Comments, 
        ISDATE(DateString) As IsDate
FROM @T;

SET DATEFORMAT YDM;

SELECT  DateString, 
        Comments, 
        ISDATE(DateString) As IsDate
FROM @T;
```

Results:

```
DateString      Comments                    IsDate
1752-12-31      will always return false    0
1753-01-01      will always return true     1
2018-02-27      depends on dateformat       1
2018-27-02      depends on dateformat       0

DateString      Comments                    IsDate
1752-12-31      will always return false    0
1753-01-01      will always return true     1
2018-02-27      depends on dateformat       0
2018-27-02      depends on dateformat       1
```

Comment: Thank you, but here i am not getting a FALSE/TRUE result, but error. Even `ISDATE('ABC')` is not produced an error.

Comment: because you are passing a date date type into the `isdate` function, which is explicitly forbidden. I'm still working on my answer, Will have more details soon.

Comment: SELECT  ISDATE(CAST(MyDate AS VARCHAR)),* FROM TBL      Here you are casting the value to Varchar then comparing the value if they are valid date or not